# how to send 150 GB of data from server to server

Tags: server, database

I have 2 Ubuntu 18.04 dedicated servers and I want to copy 150 GB of data from desktop on server 1 to desktop on server 2.
I have XRDP access.

Comment: Seems like a job for scp or rsync...if you have shell access, too. Must it be GUI?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `ssh`/`scp`

steps

- make sure `ssh-server` is installed in server 2: `sudo apt install ssh-server`
- make sure the ssh-service is enabled on server 2: `sudo systemctl enable ssh`
- initiate a ssh connection from server 1 to server 2:

  ```
  user@server1%> ssh server2
  ```

  (the first time you will be asked for confirmation about the host key)
- create a target directory `mkdir data`
- close that connection again
  I assume the data on server 1 are located in a common directory, say `~/data`
- use `scp` to copy the data

  ```
  scp -r ~/data/ server2:data
  ```

  `-r` tells `scp` to copy recursively

Comment: Thanks. I will try this soon as my server 2 is ready.  Server2 is ip address or some other name? Lets say Fredo@245.112.156.213%> ssh 231.253.132.117

Comment: Yes, IP address is fine. I assume you have the same username on both servers?

Comment: yes. name is same :)
thank you !!